# What are the ways to browse the web without exposing a a manually operated computer's IP address?

Tags: web-browser, terminology

I figure these as the ways to browse the web without exposing a manually operated computer's IP address:

- Proxy (such as "download from us" proxy)
- VPN
- TOR
- Using a remote GUI operating system (via, say, TeamViewer).

There might be more ways but I don't know the professional terminology to look at some data about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- A proxy and a VPN do the same thing. You connect to a machine that then connects to the target site. VPN just adds encryption.
- Tor does the same thing as a proxy, but it spreads out the process over a chain of machines.
- Remote access browses from the remote machine, but you access *that* machine remotely.
- There is also "browser isolation" that is a more efficient form of "remote access".

They are all doing the same thing; they are breaking the connection between you and the target. Each option provides different other protections depending on what you want to be protected from, and each has a different impact in terms of resources and experience. If you want to stream video, Tor is not a great option, for example.

If you describe what you want to be protected from, then the solutions will be easier to provide. Asking for a list of all the potential solutions is difficult to answer, especially without knowing what threats you want to counter and what constraints you might have.